# React native date picker shows the previous date on selecting a Date

Tags: react-native, datepicker

I am using React Native date picker and it shows falsy date. If I choose 02 January, 2017. The value in View is 01 january 2017.

```
<DatePicker
  date={displayDate}
  mode="date"
  minDate={"1970/01/01"}
  androidMode="spinner"
  format="dddd MM/DD/YYYY"
  confirmBtnText="Confirm"
  cancelBtnText="Cancel"
  showIcon={false}
  onDateChange={(date) => {
    let dateTime, time, newDate;
    newDate = dateFormatter.getDateOnlyByUserTimeZone(date, this.props.user.timeZone)
    time = dateFormatter.getLTZTimeOnlyFromUTC(this.props.caseCopy.caseDate, this.props.user.timeZone)
    this.onChangeCaseDateTime(newDate, time)
  }}
/>
```

Can someone suggest a possible work around?

Comment: Probably timezone-related. But we are missing some info. Where does displayDate come from? What does onChangeCaseDateTime do? ... Can you create a working example? Like a snack.expo.io which we can try.

Comment: react native doesn't have component called `DatePicker`, are you using `DatePickerIOS` or third party lib?